# Capture standart output of powershell script executed from .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Let's assume that I have very simple powershell script `myscript.ps1`, which writes to standart output:

```
get-location
```

Now I want to execute this script from .net application. I ended up with next code:

```
var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = "-file \"myscript.ps1\"",
                WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "run"),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        };

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

And it works, but I think it should be more elegant way to do it using `System.Management.Automation` assembly:

```
using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    shell.Commands.AddScript("myscript.ps1");
    var r = shell.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

But `Invoke` returns collection of `PSObject, and I can't find way to get access to stdout

Comment: Isn't this the output? Try to print your PSObjects  `foreach (PSObject result in shell.Invoke())
          {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result.ToString());
          }`

Comment: @PeterSchneider tryed, in this case it's empty collection

Comment: What's in `result.Members` ?

Comment: Another way would be to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to start the external command and redirect output. [Here](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) you can find an example...

Comment: @Uriil please understand that `powershell.exe` not only outputs the result but also formats it

Answer (score 0):

On "myscript.ps1" put at the end Out-String